# Hibernate find by Primary Key In List Direct to L2 Cache

Tags: hibernate, jpa, primary-key, cpu-cache

I have an Entity with a simple long primary key.
I do a Query like: Select from table where primary_key IN (....);

Hibernate seems to want to do a query to get the Ids (that I just specified!) and then go to the L2 cache. Is there any way to skip the initial query? I just want a set of Entities by primary key.
Not sure if this is a JPA 1, vs JPA 2.0 (which supports Lists better).

I can do findById() in a loop and get the desired result, but this is obviously not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable [query caching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache) and this specific query as cache able. This only available in JPA 2.0 via hints.

```
query.setHint(“org.hibernate.cacheable”, true);
```

And enable the query cache by setting the following property

```
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache true
```

Another solution would be to use getReference in  a loop and enable batch loading. If the instance exists in the cache it will be returned from cache - if not when the first proxied object is accessed it will fire one query to load a batch of those. You could hide this behind a utility function.

```
public List<T> findMany(Class<T> entityClass,List<? extends Serializable> ids) {
  List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>;
  for(Serializable id:ids) {
     result.add(entityManager.getRefrence(id));
  }

  for(T entity:result) {
    // force initialization of proxies, if batch loading is enabled
    // this shouldn't lead to one query per entity
    Hibernate.initialize(entity); 
  }
  return result;      
}
```

This might need a few tweaks - haven't tested it - especially the generics part.

Comment: I'm not sure that's all of it. I already enable the query cache, and what I see happening is that Hibernate will do a query: select ids in (ids) which is a bit silly.. cache that... and then go get the entities by id...

Comment: have you set the specific query as cacheable. Also any update / insert of the same entity will invalidate the cache.

Comment: This isn't the issue. I'm asking for Entities by ID. Any cached query would just contain the same set of Ids.  It's not that query caching isn't working... It's that it is unnecessary, and as you point out.. updates/inserts invalidate the cache... which is pointless... because I'm still asking for Entities by ID. My work around for this was to override the StandardQueryCache and have it return the same set of Ids I passed in.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't analyze queries to figure out if it is only a id look up - it can end up being quite complex to implement.  I have updated the answer to provide an workaround to achieve what you are looking for.